# How to write a formula that skip other criteria`s and apply only the chosen values from the drop down list?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets in excel file with two tables:

**Sheet 1:**
Table 1 having columns [A,B,C,D]

**Comment:**
This table is a filtered table containing multiple rows having multiple values
I can filter directly from the header drop down to get the specific row related to the criteria I choose in the headers.

**Sheet 2:**
Table 2 having Columns [A,B,C,D] and Cell [A4]

**Comment:**
This table is a Filter Summary table for each column contain a drop down list containing a list of values , the user can choose one in each column to filter the table 1 in a formula located inside the Cell A4.
**Cell A4** containing the formula that will calculate the number of rows in table 1, after applying the criteria chosen from the table 2.

**Question**
If i want to filter by two column or three columns only and not by all the columns located inside the table 2, how to write a formula that skip other criteria`s and apply only the chosen values from the table 2?

**Code:**
Cell A4 contains the following code:
=COUNTIFS(QA_ITEMS!A:A,$A$4,QA_ITEMS!B:B,$B$4,QA_ITEMS!C:C,$C$4,QA_ITEMS!D:D,$D$4)

Attached for your reference.
[Adding-Multiple Criteria in a formula dynamically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om2yj.png)

Comment: Does the proposed solution works for you?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I used named ranges, you can also hardcode the ranges or use a table:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(
 (IF(ISBLANK(F2),MATCH("*",phase,0),F2=phase))*
 (IF(ISBLANK(G2),MATCH("*",sprint,0),G2=sprint))*
 (IF(ISBLANK(H2),MATCH("*",Item,0),H2=Item))*
 (IF(ISBLANK(I2),MATCH("*",type,0),I2=type)))
```

Cheers,
Michal

Comment: Thank you Michal I will try it . :)